# How to convert a string literal type to the keys of a new type?

Tags: typescript

Let's suppose I have a string literal type:

```
type Letters = "a" | "b" | "c" | "d" | "e";
```

How can I create the following type based on `Letters`?

```
type LetterFlags = {a: boolean, b: boolean, c: boolean, d: boolean, e: boolean};
```

---

I have tried

```
type Flags<T> = { [k in keyof T]: boolean };
type LetterFlags = Flags<Letters>;
```

but

```
const flags: LetterFlags = {a: true, b: false, c: true, d: false, e: true};
```

raises

```
Type '{ a: boolean; b: boolean; c: boolean; d: boolean; e: boolean; }' is not assignable to type '"e"'.
```

Comment: `Record<Letters, boolean>` would work. Your attempt `{ [k in keyof T]: boolean }` would be fixed by just removing `keyof`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do like this:

```
type Letters = "a" | "b" | "c" | "d" | "e";

type Flags<T extends PropertyKey> = Record<T, boolean>;
type LetterFlags = Flags<Letters>;

const flags: LetterFlags = { a: true, b: false, c: true, d: false, e: true };
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAMhzAgJwM5QLxQEQEMtQB9sAjfIrAYzOwBNqsIsBuAKBdEigDEAbHAcxQAeACpQIAD0QA7GmgAKSAPaQkoANIQQAPgxQAShApKkNUQBooxJUp4Qc07aw7Q4CZLwFpMnwULeIqE5sxtIowFAAZnyCAFyw8IG+3lAA3jjxwEgArhCWxPGRODwoeVAUmTllNIXFpZYQlbkAvkxAA)

Answer (score 1):

This is based on @Guerric P's answer.  I'm a Typescripe newb, wondering if this would also work (seems to)

```
enum Letter {
    a = "a",
    b = "b",
    c = "c",
    d = "d",
    e = "e",
}

type Flag = Record<Letter, boolean>;

const flag: Flag = {a: true, b: false, c: true, d: false, e: true};
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2#code/KYOwrgtgBAMsAu9gCcoG8BQVtQIZQF4oAiXYgGixwCNCTqKrsBjO45xnKAEze85zA2wRgF8MGeAE8ADkIBiAG1wBzOgCVgzAPbJuAHjiIU5KNW3bFwXCAB8Abgk6QAZ3hQAZspUAuKEtU6NFw-eGQwYFNqPw9cRRdIqGZQ8MTuGLiE02AUiNF7IA)